# Get model with hasMany is not working in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I try to print on my view all the atleti associated with a squadra x but the method `$squadra->atleti()` always returns me ant empty array.

Have you got some ideas to get this working?

Down below you can find my code and my db structure.
Squadra is team in english. One team can be associated to many atleti (it stands for players).

I think there is some problems with the foreign key.

Thank you for your help.

```
<?php
//Squadra Model
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Squadra extends Model
{
protected $connection = 'custom_mysql';
protected $table = 'squadra';
/**
 * Get the Allenatore for the Squadra.
 */
public function allenatore()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Allenatore');
}

/**
 * Get the Atleta for the Squadra.
 */
public function atleti()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Atleta');
}
}

<?php
//Atleta Model
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Atleta extends Model
{
protected $table = 'atleta';
protected $connection = 'custom_mysql';
/**
 * Get the Atleta for the Squadra.
 */
public function squadra() {
    return $this->belongsTo( 'App\Models\Squadra' );
}
}

<?php
//Controller
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class AtletaController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
```

public function getSquadra($id)
    {
        $squadra = Squadra::find($id);

```
    return view('custom.squadra.dettaglio', compact('squadra'));
}

 //View 
 @foreach( $squadra->atleti() as $atleta )

 <tr class="success">

<td>{{ $atleta->id }}</td>
<td>{{ $atleta->nome}}</td>
<td>{{ $atleta->cognome}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Here it is the output of `dd($squadra)`
[image]

Comment: Can you dd($athleti) in your index function, do you have any data stored in your db?

Comment: Look up here @utdev, i have edited the question with the output code of dd($squadra). And yes i have some data stored in the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are sending the atleti to the view, instead of the squadra. Try to change your controller function to this:

```
public function index()
{
    $squadra = Squadra::firstOrFail(); // You need a paremeter in a route that defines which squadra to show. This will show the first one.

    return view('custom.atleta.index', compact('squadra'));
}
```

Comment: I have some confusion in my controller. Look at the new fixed code @piscator. But nothing changes, it's still empty. Is the model code right?

Comment: @jack_0 In your view change `$squadra->atleti()` to `$squadra->atleti` or `$squadra->atleti()->get()`

Comment: Thank you so much @piscator. It works fine now. What is the difference between the two expression?

Comment: You're welcome. Both expressions return a collection. The first one is a shorthand function of the last one, using `atleti` as a dynamic property. `$squadra->atleti()` returns `lluminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` and then get() returns the collection. Could you please accept the answer? Thank you!